# Snap.svg scale and animate SVG

Tags: javascript, css, animation, svg, snap.svg

I'm trying to scale my SVG with `g.animate({ transform: "s2.5,2.5," + bbox.cx + "," + bbox.cy }, 0);` and then animate `wheelAnimation(bbox.cx, bbox.cy, 1500);`

```
var i = 0;
function wheelAnimation(cx, cy, speed){
    i++;
    g.animate(
        { transform: "r360," + cx + ',' + cy}, // Basic rotation around a point. No frills.
        speed, // Nice slow turning rays
        function(){
            if(i == 5)
                speed = 5000;
            g.attr({ transform: 'rotate(0 ' + cx + ' ' + cy}); // Reset the position of the rays.
            wheelAnimation(cx,cy, speed); // Repeat this animation so it appears infinite.
        }
    );
}
```

But my SVG didn't scaling. It's only rotates. If I remove rotation - SVG scaling. How to combine it to immediately scale and then animate rotation?

[Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Shyhvs0uKI4l6jvDjMZr?p=preview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never used Snap.svg but you might try this:

```
var i = 0;

function wheelAnimation(cx, cy, speed, scale){
   i++;
   g.attr({ transform: "r0 " + cx + " " + cy + " s" + scale + "," + scale + "," + cx + "," + cy }); //Reset + Scale setup
   g.animate({ 
      transform: "r360," + cx + "," + cy + " s" + scale + "," + scale + "," + cx + "," + cy }, // Basic rotation around a point. No frills.
      speed, // Nice slow turning rays
      function(){
         if(i == 5)
            speed = 5000;
         wheelAnimation(cx, cy, speed, scale); // Repeat this animation so it appears infinite.
      }
   );
}
```

Hope this helps you :)

[See Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/96B6TktoenyRQrB7B3KK?p=preview)